# Ошибка при компиляции в арк. Unity 2D

Tags: unity3d

Весь день вчера искал решение, так и не нашел. Удаление папки Assets\Temp, Ignore Grandle Version не помогло. Все ошибки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1

```
> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
It will be removed in a future version of the Android Gradle plugin, and will no longer allow you to disable R8.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

2

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':launcher'.
> android.defaultConfig.versionCode is set to 0, but it should be a positive integer.
  See https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning#appversioning for more information.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

3

```
    CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
E:\Programs\Unity\2020.3.12f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "E:\Programs\Unity\2020.3.12f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.6.4.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':launcher'.
> android.defaultConfig.versionCode is set to 0, but it should be a positive integer.
  See https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning#appversioning for more information.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
It will be removed in a future version of the Android Gradle plugin, and will no longer allow you to disable R8.
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <dc14d30a5e0540ee9311ed6df63d9074>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

4

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 227 seconds (226859 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

5

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ca] in <dc14d30a5e0540ee9311ed6df63d9074>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <dc14d30a5e0540ee9311ed6df63d9074>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

Comment: Выложите полное описание ошибки. Что-то важное как минимум есть в 3 блоке после "sderr"

Comment: Ох, спасибо. Я уже починил (переустановил юнити хаб, юнити, обновил джаву)

Comment: А нет. Ошибка опять начала появляться при билде на андроид... Дополнил 3-й блок